# dynamic url with iframe using javascript in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, dynamic

The script in the html below works as expected. It loads the latest version of a page by getting today's date info and modifying the iframe src.

But when I put just the script into a WordPress code module for a section of a page, it takes over the whole page. I suspect the problem is the use of `document.body.innerHTML`, but I don't know what the correct javascript code is.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var h = h > 12 ? h - 12 + 'PM' : h + 'AM';
if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
}
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
}
var today = mm + '%2f' + dd + '%2f' + yyyy;
document.body.innerHTML += ' <iframe src="https://www.colorado.gov/airquality/site.aspx?aqsid=080770020&seeddate= ' + today + '" width = "100%" height ="600"> </iframe> ';
</script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: do `document.body.innerHTML +=`

Comment: This solves the problem of the iframe taking over the whole page. But now the content of the iframe is missing. This can be seen at `https://www.citizensforcleanair.org`. The iframe is supposed to show the url in the lower right corner.

Comment: do `<iframe src="https://www.colorado.gov/airquality/site.aspx?aqsid=080770020&seeddate= '+today+'" width = "100%" height ="600"> </iframe>` instead.

Comment: This helps, but I'm still not seeing the url in the lower right corner of the page. See citizensforcleanair.org. The javascript console reports a syntax error Unexpected token <

Comment: don't delete the `' '`. do like so `'<iframe src="https://www.colorado.gov/airquality/site.aspx?aqsid=080770020&seeddate= '+today+'" width = "100%" height ="600"> </iframe>'`

Comment: With the corrections suggested and some more as added to the corrected script in the main question, the src in the iframe shows up in the home page of www.citizensforcleanair.org. But it is below the iframe contents that show the purple air map rather than to the right of it.

Comment: do this then `document.getElementsByClassName('et_pb_code_inner')[1].innerHTML += ' <iframe src="https://www.colorado.gov/airquality/site.aspx?aqsid=080770020&seeddate= ' + today + '" width = "100%" height ="600"> </iframe> ';`

Comment: That did it. Check out www.citizensforclearnair.org. If you make this a comment I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('et_pb_code_inner')[1].innerHTML += ' <iframe src="https://www.colorado.gov/airquality/site.aspx?aqsid=080770020&seeddate= ' + today + '" width = "100%" height ="600"> </iframe> ';
```